How to create a combined node list in xslt
This is my input
<all>
    <list1>
        <name>x</name>
        <name>y</name>
    </list1>
    <list2>
        <process>
            <value>1</value>
            <value>2</value>
        </process>
        <process>
            <value>1</value>
            <value>2</value>
            <value>3</value>
        </process>
        <process>
            <value>1</value>
        </process>
    </list2>
</all>

my expected output is
<list3>
    <object>
        <process>
            <name>x</name>
            <value>1</value>
        </process>
        <process>
            <name>y</name>
            <value>2</value>
        </process>
    </object>
    
    <object>
        <process>
            <name>x</name>
            <value>1</value>
        </process>
        <process>
            <name>y</name>
            <value>2</value>
        </process>
        <process>
            <value>3</value>
        </process>
    </object>
    
    <object>
        <process>
            <name>x</name>
            <value>1</value>
        </process>
        <process>
            <value>2</value>
        </process>
        <process>
            <value>3</value>
        </process>
    </object>
    
</list3>

This is my code
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xalan="xml.apache.org/xalan">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!--Identity Trasnform -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() |@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="all">
        <list3>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/all/list2/process"/>
        </list3>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="process">
        <object>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </object>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="value">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <process>
            <xsl:if test="//list1/name[$pos]">
                <name><xsl:value-of select="//list1/name[$pos]"/></name>
            </xsl:if>
            <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>
        </process>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

The output I have achieved is
<list3>
    <object>
        <process>
            <name>x</name>
            <value>1</value>
        </process>
        <process>
            <name>y</name>
            <value>2</value>
        </process>
    </object>
    <object>
        <process>
            <name>x</name>
            <value>1</value>
        </process>
        <process>
            <name>y</name>
            <value>2</value>
        </process>
        <process>
            <value>3</value>
        </process>
    </object>
    <object>
        <process>
            <name>x</name>
            <value>1</value>
        </process>
    </object>
</list3>

My problem is the template match is based on list2/process/value which works well when I have lesser number of nodes than list1/name. How do I add the extra nodes in list1 based on position when i get only fewer "matches" from list2/process/value?
I am trying to achieve this without using a for-each loop is possible.

Could you explain why in your expected output the last object contains 3 process elements?

I just mocked up to simulate what is actually needed at work. Technically, what i will need is a to have full list of elements in either of the branches (list1 and 2)

Meaning the last contains still 3 process or 2 as I would maybe think?

I think you want to process the max number of items between value and name e.g.
  <xsl:template match="list2/process">
    <xsl:variable name="root" select="/"/>
    <xsl:variable name="process" select="."/>
    <object>
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to max((count(value), count($root/all/list1/name)))">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="."/>
        <process>
          <xsl:sequence select="$process/value[$pos], $root/all/list1/name[$pos]"/>
        </process>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </object>
  </xsl:template>

or perhaps better
  <xsl:template match="list2/process">
    <xsl:variable name="names" select="/all/list1/name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="process" select="."/>
    <object>
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to max((count(value), count($names)))">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="."/>
        <process>
          <xsl:sequence select="$process/value[$pos], $names[$pos]"/>
        </process>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </object>
  </xsl:template>

